# Filter single element from a multi value element in JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson, rest-assured

In my test I need to compare the expected and actual JSON response. But the JSON response is limited depending upon the role. So I need to exclude certain fields while comparing.
Below is the JSON and I want to filter out 2 things from it.
1. CompanyId
                                                                                                            2. status.

```
{
userId=dg4d6g4dg45-rgdre-543-dfg,
userName=test123,
effectives=[  
   {  
     companyId=345634-54-547-74,
     companyName=xyz,
     roleId=685-345863490-634,
     roleName=This is the test Role
  },
  {  
     companyId=345634-54-547-74,
     companyName=xyz,
     roleId=685-345863490-634,
     roleName=This is the test Role
  }
],
status=Active
}
```

Can you someone please let me know how to achieve this. 
I explored the filterOutAllExcep method of SimpleBeanPropertyFilter but then I will have to figure out the logic to remember all the fields that should be included as well.

Comment: Are you using an object mapper and mapping to a class? If you are, you can ignore elements you don't want by just not defining them in the class and adding @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) to the class.

Comment: IMO the correct way is to have separate tests for each role. I don't think it's an issue that you will have 2 very similar JSON bodies.

Comment: @PatrickStephen - I am using an object mapper but i dont want to add ignore annotation in the data model class. I would like to do it at run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have found a resolution for this. 
I am using Object Mapper and converting the data model into a Map.
Then iterating over the map and removing the fields.
Flat filtering is straight forward but had to right up some logic for nested fields.

```
        // Convert the DataModel into a Map object
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map mainObjectMap = mapper.convertValue(object, Map.class);
```